# mapWith with hasMany giving error on run-app with Grails v3.3.5 working fine with Grails v3.2.11

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class, grails-3.3, domain-mapping

I have a domain class DomainA --

```
class DomainA {
    String someString

    static mapWith = "none"
}
```

I don't want to persist this domain so I am using [mapWith](http://docs.grails.org/3.3.5/ref/Domain%20Classes/mapWith.html) property. And have its relation in DomainB in hasMany --

```
class DomainB {
  String anotherString

  static hasMany = [domainAs: DomainA]
}
```

This code is working fine with Grails v3.2.11 but giving following error with Grails v3.3.x.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'methodValidationPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'methodValidationPostProcessor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastoreServiceRegistry': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1071)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:225)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:703)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:84)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:393)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:380)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
        at upgrade.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastoreServiceRegistry': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:927)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:804)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:564)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:432)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:206)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1267)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:279)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
        ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:271)
        ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.getTableName(GrailsDomainBinder.java:1202)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.calculateTableForMany(GrailsDomainBinder.java:1155)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.bindCollectionTable(GrailsDomainBinder.java:1105)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.bindCollection(GrailsDomainBinder.java:1052)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder$CollectionType$1.create(GrailsDomainBinder.java:3463)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.createClassProperties(GrailsDomainBinder.java:1872)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues(GrailsDomainBinder.java:1751)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.bindRoot(GrailsDomainBinder.java:1391)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.contribute(GrailsDomainBinder.java:165)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:275)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.java:276)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:86)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:39)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:23)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:64)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:52)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.ConnectionSourcesInitializer.create(ConnectionSourcesInitializer.groovy:24)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore.<init>(HibernateDatastore.java:204)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1076)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
        ... 51 common frames omitted
```

I searched for its solution or any workaround but did not get anything.
Anyone have any idea how can I fix the issue. Thanks!

Note -- I am using Gradle v3.5.

Comment: I think, a problem in gorm and grails-hibernate versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the following comment by **Ben Rhine** on [this issue](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10994) this is not supported from **Grails 3.x**.

> In looking into this issue this is improper usage of the mapWith static property. The issue is not really the mapWith property but that you have a hasMany on an un-persisted class as that is not supported.
>
> While this may have worked previously (verified your described behavior works up through 3.2.13 with Gorm 6.0.x) it was not a feature, this does not work in Grails 3.3.x with Gorm 6.1.x as relationships such as hasMany will not work with un-persisted classes.
>
> I would suggest you reconsider your relationship mapping and you may not even need mapWith when your done.